# How to stop Bot generate Traffic in Wordpress?

Tags: googlebot, spam-prevention, spam-blocker, spam-bots

My WordPress website recent facing a big problem. Spamming problem. Using a plugin i detect that every single second here coming huge number of traffic which is fake and send by BOT. The traffic also not referral, not showing in Analytics. For this problem the CPU usage being 100% in seconds. like this the visitor coming...

[image]

Also there have some plugin but where the link need to put manually. But it's not actually possible. because here Coming huge number of sites in seconds. How can i solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you may not be aware, but the last visit to your site (highlighted in yellow) is from GoogleBot (Google's crawling bot, also referred to as a spider). I can't tell you this is the source of your problem, but if your intent is to block Google, it's best to use disallow instructions on your robots.txt file, or a noindex,nofollow on each page that you do not want indexed.

Comment: Wordpress has very effective ways of preventing spam, between using plugins or a free cdn such as cloudflare - which also help prevent bogging down resources and bandwidth within your hosting instance.

Comment: Thank you for comment. while Clouflare plugin deal with caching related issue. I am using wp-super-cache. The CPU resources getting high while the traffic coming to site. Here i need to know the link showing as Bot traffic is this bad or good?

Comment: Cloudflare enhances the following: 1. Performance (save resources & improve speed), 2. Reduced Bandwidth, 3. Spam protection (filter out bad traffic and protect yourself from automated bots & spammers), 4. Faster DNS Changes/Propagation, 5. Blocks Dos & DDos Attacks (which blocks automated requests meant to overload your server and bring it down). Therefore, since Cloudflare passess traffic that would normally arrive at your site through a filter process & only validated traffic will be routed to your host. Cloudflare is different than your typical CDN.

Comment: Thank you. Had no idea how better it can work. i find that here two ways to install. 
1. Cloudflare Wordpress Plugin
2. activate Cloudflare cpanel plugin

but the wordpress cloudflare plugin review not that much good. Which one you recommend to do...

Comment: I guess this could be a possible DDOS attack. Better to chose a good firewall like CloudFlare to protect your site.

Comment: You will need to create a free cloudflare account here: https://www.cloudflare.com/a/sign-up. Be sure to make a copy of all of your DNS settings prior to changing your nameservers to Cloudflare's. Not all of your records will transfer over & once you move DNS to Cloudflare, settings can be permanently lost (even if you attempt to move DNS back to your original registrar/host). After signing up, there is a wealth of ways to configure with wordpress, start here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/. I think you are making a wise move,  best of luck!